# How to use basic auth in express.js with some anonymous endpoints?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication

I'm creating an express api in node and thanks to `express-basic-auth`, setting up basic authentication is as easy as

```
app.use(basicAuth({
    users: { 'username': 'password' }
}));
```

However this protects all endpoints in the app, and I would like to configure some of them to allow anonymous access. What would be the best way to do about doing that?